# splitting into train test by train_test_split of float values?

Tags: scikit-learn, cross-validation, training, class-imbalance, encoding

How to **split** into **train test** by train_test_split of float values ?
I used **LabelEncoder** but I have about 300K lines and when I used the **cross_val** I saw `ValueError: The least populated class in y has only 1 member, which is too few. The minimum number of groups for any class cannot be less than 2., what is the better solution?`

```
 X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=seed )  

    from imblearn.under_sampling import RandomUnderSampler
    from collections import Counter

    rus = RandomUnderSampler(random_state=seed, return_indices=True) # (50:50)

    from sklearn import preprocessing
    lab_enc = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
    training_scores_encoded = lab_enc.fit_transform(y_train)
    #print(training_scores_encoded)

    X_res, y_res, idx_res = rus.fit_sample(X_train, training_scores_encoded)

    from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

    scalerT = StandardScaler().fit(X_train[:,[0]])
    #scalerT = StandardScaler().fit(X[:,[0]])

    X_train[:,[0]] = scalerT.transform(X_train[:,[0]])
    X_test[:,[0]] = scalerT.transform(X_test[:,[0]])
    X_res[:,[0]] = scalerT.transform(X_res[:,[0]])

    scalerA = StandardScaler().fit(X_train[:,[idx_Amount]])
    #scalerA = StandardScaler().fit(X[:,[idx_Amount]])

    X_train[:,[idx_Amount]] = scalerA.transform(X_train[:,[idx_Amount]])
    X_test[:,[idx_Amount]] = scalerA.transform(X_test[:,[idx_Amount]])
    X_res[:,[idx_Amount]] = scalerA.transform(X_res[:,[idx_Amount]])

    from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression


    models = []
    models.append(('LR', LogisticRegression()))


    # Default parameters for each model
    models

    from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
    from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit

    XX = X_res
    yy = y_res

    #StratifiedKFold is used by default for cv integer
    #cv=10
    cv = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=10, test_size=0.3, random_state=seed)
results = []
names = []

for name, model in models:
    cv_results = cross_val_score(model, XX, yy, cv = cv, scoring = 'accuracy')
    results.append(cv_results)
    names.append(name)
    msg = "%s: %.2f (+/- %.2f)" % (name, cv_results.mean(), cv_results.std())
    print(msg)

fig = plt.figure()
fig.suptitle('Accuracy')
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.boxplot(results)
ax.set_xticklabels(names)
plt.show()

results = []
names = []

from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit

XX = X_res
yy = y_res

#StratifiedKFold is used by default for cv integer
#cv=10
cv = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=10, test_size=0.3, random_state=seed)

for name, model in models:
    cv_results = cross_val_score(model, XX, yy, cv = cv, scoring = 'recall')
    results.append(cv_results)
    names.append(name)
    msg = "%s: %.2f (+/- %.2f)" % (name, cv_results.mean(), cv_results.std())
    print(msg)
```

Comment: Please post some code so that we can debug.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your data violates the requirements of StratifiedShuffleSplit, specifically it's not possible to do a 70:30 split of the data and maintain the same number of distinct y values in the test and train set - most likely because you have a y value which only occurs 1 time?

Perhaps just use ShuffleSplit?

Comment: In my code I had it but I omit it by mistake when deleting the unrelated lines!You can check it now! This is not the reason of my problem!